# How to remove cookie data from static content request?

Tags: magento-1.9, url, cookie

I have created a separate domain to serve static content. Also modified URL values in System->Configuration->General->Web.

When I inspect any static content request with firebug in firefox browser, I can see frontend and adminhtml cookies data are also attached to that request.

I want to remove that cookie data from request. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please take your time to accept an answer if it helped you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You also have to set the cookie domain explicitly in *System > COnfiguration > General > Web > Session Cookie Management*:

[image: screenshot]

If you leave it empty, Magento uses `.example.com` with a leading dot, which also matches all subdomains.

Comment: I've noticed on cookie path change, the affect is not reflecting on storefront unless the cookies are removed. And to ask store customers to delete their cookies is not a practical solution. Is there a way to make the changes (related to cookie) reflect instantly for customers?

Comment: You could do it with a temporary Javascript that deletes the cookie with the old values

Comment: I tried the same thing but still, it adds a leading dot on `form_key` and `PHPSESSID` cookie, do you have any idea for this? or is this correct behavior? as we have multiple stores and we don't want to share cookie across domains @FabianSchmengler